# What's the meaning difference of "get to"?

Tags: meaning

> 1. He started getting to family dinners on time.
> 2. He started having family dinners on time.

Is there any meaning difference by adding "getting to" on the first sentence?

Comment: You haven't provided enough context.  "He started getting to family dinners on time" could mean that, but it could also mean that he started arriving to them on time.  The way that it would mean he started having them on time would be by way of the implication that he started a new habit of preparing them timely so that dinner would be served at the appointed time.  There is no way to know what is really meant by "getting to" in that sentence without further context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two sentences *may* mean the same thing—or they may not. It depends on how you interpret **getting to**.

Unless the *he* in the sentence is responsible for hosting or cooking family dinners, a different similarity in meaning could be:

1. He started getting to family dinners on time.
2. He started arriving at family dinners on time.

Note that I would say the same thing if the sentence read *she started getting to*. My assumption has nothing to do with gender, but the meaning of the phrase **getting to**.

Some possible alternate sentences that include **getting to** in the **arriving at** sense:

> She starting getting to work at 8:30 every morning.
>   They started getting to airports a couple hours early to make sure they didn't miss their flights.
>   We won't be getting to the cottage this weekend.

Of course, you *could* also mean **getting to** in the **doing** or **having** sense that you originally used:

> He started getting a newspaper delivered every morning.
>   You started getting salads for your lunches.
>   They started getting their activities monitored by the spy across the street.

So, your two sentences only mean the same thing in one sense. It depends on what you are trying to express in the first sentence.